# Set full-width on input

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I set full width on input elements inside a radio group?

I'm using the following setup to create two options (user can either upload a file or specify a URL):

```
<v-radio-group v-model="photo_mode">
    <v-layout row align-baseline>
    <v-radio value="file" />
    <v-file-input v-model="eitem.photo" class="mr-4 mt-0" :disabled="photo_mode=='url'" />
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row align-baseline>
    <v-radio value="url" />
    <v-text-field v-model="eitem.photo_url" class="mr-4 mt-0" :disabled="photo_mode=='file'" />
    </v-layout>
</v-radio-group>
```

The looks fine except that both `v-file-input` and `v-text-field` are not as wide as the container. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

As you see, the `v-text-field` above the radio group (Details field) is correctly showing full-width, but the two inputs inside the radio group are not.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. This is a bug in Vue. Already reported [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5416). The solution is to simply add the following CSS in your `App.vue`:

```
<style>
  .v-input--selection-controls .v-input__control{
      width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Make sure the style section is not marked with `scoped` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I also needed to set the style of v-label too, in order for this workaround to function properly. Also I used scoped css locally in the component:

```
.radio-group-full-width >>> .v-input__control {
   width: 100%
}

.radio-group-full-width >>> .v-label {
  width: 100%
}
```

So in the template:

```
<v-radio-group class="radio-group-full-width">
```